# PHP - Search Using Form and Return Back Records

Tags: php

I am working in PHP/HTML/SQLITE3. I have a database that consist of several tables, one of the tables is called Item, which contains an itemID, name of item, and so forth. So my search takes the user input of the itemID and what I am suppose to return back is everything associated with that itemID.

I have tested out my search and it does return back the itemID, however, I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to return back everything related to the itemID. Down below are my search form and what I have for a seperate file which contains the query.

```
<form method="POST" action="action.php">
    <input name="search" type="text" size="20" maxlength="10"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

## -----

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
        $itemID = $_POST["search"];

    try {
        $db->beginTransaction();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE itemID = '$itemID';";
        $result = $db->query($query);

        if (empty($_POST['search'])){
            echo "<strong>You didn't fill in anything!</strong>";
        }
        else {
            echo $itemID;
        }

        $db->commit();
        }
    $db = null;
    ?>
```

Edit Code (Addition of attempt at fetchall):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
    $itemID = $_POST["search"];

try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE itemID = '$itemID';";
    #$result = $db->query($query);
    $result = sqlite_fetch_all($query, SQLITE_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $entry) {
        echo 'ItemID: ' . $entry['itemID'] . ' Item Name' . $entry['name'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['search'])){
        echo "<strong>Esteemed customer did not fill in a 
        itemID number, please search again. </strong>";
    }

    $db->commit();
    }
```

2nd Attempt:

```
 <?php
    $dbname = "mydatabase.db";

  try {
    // Establish connection to "mydatabase.db"
    $db = new PDO("sqlite:" . $dbname);

    // Set error handling so that errors throw an exception
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Enable foreign key constraints on the database
    $db->exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "SQLite connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
  }

    if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
        $itemID = $_POST["search"];

    try {
        $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE itemID = '$itemID'");
        #$query = "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE itemID = '$itemID';";
        #$result = $db->query($query);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        print_r($result);

        #if (empty($_POST['search'])){
            #echo "<strong>Esteemed customer did not fill in a 
            #itemID number, please search again. </strong>";
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like you just need to fetch the `$result` resource

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the query after executing it. Do a fetch. Also you are open to SQL injections with this code.

Comment: Ah so I should replace my $result with: $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); instead?

Thanks for letting me know chris, this is for a small class project so it'll not be going live. :-)

Comment: Even in the future though for your own input if you have a `'` present your query will fail. You should really use parameterized queries. You need to execute the query, then fetch the results after. Use `fetchAll` or loop the fetch. If you call it as your current example shows you would only get the first row. Also use the `@` to tag users, notifications aren't sent otherwise.

Comment: @chris, Hi Chris, I had made attempts using fetchall but it does not work. Could you please look at my updated post and let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are using `pdo`, right? http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Yup, I am using PDO. I have revised it again with your guidance but I am getting a huge error with the page not running. If I am correct, this should just return back all of the rows associated with the itemID.

Answer (score -1):

You should concatenate the itemid to the query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE itemID = '" . $itemID . "';";
```

Comment: why? variables within double quoted strings are interpolated